# Creating a pending to send in Android

Tags: java, android, barcode

I have to do an Android app that can read a barcode and send the info, but the phone may not always have internet, is one way i can have it pending to send until i have internet?

Comment: Sure. Just save the info that needs to be sent until a wifi connection is made either while the app is running in the background or when the app is launched again.

Comment: Ok perfect and how i can save that info (add it into a sqlite) or it is a simple way to save it?

Comment: Yeah, there are a few ways: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html